# WSOD after migrating from Linux to Windows

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpstorm, wsod

Originally I had my website locally setup on my laptop which is Linux and had recently migrated my work from there to my main PC - Windows. My reason for moving my work over is that I found the kind of Linux I am using to be incredibly buggy where the connection would constantly disconnect even though the internet was fine or it would take an incredibly long time to refresh the website.

I am now using XAMPP instead of manually having a localhost with PHP, Apache and MySQL set up. The IDE I am also using now is PhpStorm which is directly connected to my phpmyadmin.

Now my problem is that now I get the WSOD - White Screen Of Death, when I, lets say, try to register someone through my website this blank white screen comes up with NO errors displayed and I have looked at every possible help that I could find to fix this. Yet no success, so now I'm stuck in limbo as to whether my code is the problem or something else is, I just can't tell.

This is the same when I try my login feature as well.

This worked fine on my laptop, despite the minor errors here and there.

I have error reporting enabled and I have tried enabling it in the `php.ini` file which only gets ignored or makes XAMPP reject it (not work).

Here is my code anyways for both the database and registration, just to give an example:

Register.php:

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
$lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$confirmpassword = isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) ? $_POST['confirmpassword'] : '';

$message[] = '';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{

  //var_dump($password, $confirmpassword);
  if(strlen($password) > 6 && strlen($password) < 32)
  {

    if($password == $confirmpassword)
    {
      $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = :username');
      $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
      $records->execute();
      $results = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      //var_dump($results);

      if(count($results) > 0)
      {
        echo 'That username is already in use, please use a different one.';

      }
      else
      {
        $emailRecords = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = :email');
        $emailRecords->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $emailRecords->execute();
        $emailResults = $emailRecords->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($emailResults) > 0)
        {
          echo 'That email is already in use, are you sure you\'re not registered with us already? <a href="loginPage.php">Login Here</a>';
        }
        else
        {

          $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Firstname, Lastname, Role, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :role, :email, :username, :passwords)";
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', strip_tags($firstname));
          $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', strip_tags($lastname));
          $stmt->bindParam(':role', $_POST['role']);
          $stmt->bindParam(':email', strip_tags($email));
          $stmt->bindParam(':username',strip_tags($username));
          $stmt->bindParam(':passwords',strip_tags($hashPassword));

          if ($stmt->execute())
          {
            echo 'Well done! You have successfully registered with us!';
            header('Location:loginPage.php');
          }
          else
          {
            echo 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
            //$message = 'There seems to be an issue getting you registered.';
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
      //$message = 'Your passwords do not match, please enter them correctly.';
      //header('Location:registerPage.php');
    }
}
else
{
  echo 'Your password must be between 6 to 32 characters.';
  //header('Location:registerPage.php');
}
}
```

Database - Table users: (Required by login and register)

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Role VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Email ON users (Email);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Username ON users (Username);
```

Comment: You want the error reporting lines to come before `require 'connection.php';`

Comment: Just confirming that you put all of your files in the web root of XAMPP?

Comment: @JayBlanchard This I didn't do. I didn't realise that was what I was meant to do. I will look into this. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver I have changed this. Thank you :)

Comment: The directory is typically C:\xampp\htdocs All of your web files should be located in this directory and sub-directories from here.

Comment: So I am to put my folder into that exact directory to make this work?

Comment: What is the URL that you are seeing in a browser when doing this page?

Comment: The URL I get is http://localhost:63342/repos/bla/web/register.php or whichever page that I happen to be on.

Comment: Thnx. You are not using your XAMPP. It's PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server that ATM has issues with serving POST requests. Use proper Apache from XAMPP

Comment: Thank you. I will look into making this work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PhpStorm's own built-in web server, which has *some* issues right now (especially with POST requests, e.g. [WEB-17317](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317) -- you can watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress).

**The solution is to use your own proper web server (Apache from your XAMPP).**

1. Define Deployment entry of appropriate type. `In place` type could be fine, as long as your Apache can serve files from that location; otherwise either configure web server to be able to do that .. or use another type of deployment (e.g. `Local or Mounted Folders` for IDE to copy files to another location for you).
2. Configure it (provide desired URL etc) -- make sure it shows no warnings about unfilled fields on first 2 tabs.
3. Mark it as Default for this project.

Now IDE will use that base URL when you will use `Open in Browser` or Run/Debug actions (NOTE: it will not affect any existing Run/Debug Configurations -- only future ones; you will have to update your current Run/Debug Configurations manually).

---

What's the difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33598214/783119

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to fix my problem and now I can see the files and actually post information to my database. :)